# INSERT a new if it doesn't exist, and UPDATE if it does

Tags: mysql, replace, insert

I need to insert a new record on BD if it doesn't exist, and update if it does. For this, I use 2 queries:

```
INSERT  INTO tbl_ponto ( `rodada`, `ponto`, `patrimonio`, `FK_loginID` ) VALUES ( '10', 100.00, 100.00, 3 );
UPDATE tbl_ponto SET ponto=150.00, patrimonio=150.00 WHERE rodada=10 AND FK_loginID=3;
```

I would do this with just 1 query. I read about REPLACE but could not make it work in my case.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_ponto (`rodada`, `ponto`, `patrimonio`, `FK_loginID`)
    VALUES ('10', 100.00, 100.00, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ponto=150.00, patrimonio=150.00;
```

The trigger `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is called when the `INSERT` fails because some of the values conflict with a `PRIVATE/UNIQUE KEY` that already exists.

In this case, `rodada, FK_loginID` must be `PRIVATE KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY`, otherwise you will have to update one of those values.