# How to use SQL to insert something if it doesn't exist, and remove it if it does?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

I'm trying to write an SQL query in PHP which creates a new row, unless that row already exists, in which case delete it.

I know I can accomplish this with a SELECT, see if it's there, and then do a simple if statement to run the next query. No problem. However, I'm SURE there's a way to do this with one query, and I'd like to learn.

I have a table called "people" which has four columns: ID (unique), Name, Phone, Date. My program adds a name and phone number, which gets populated in my table. If I add a person who's already in the system, I want it to remove that person's information. Since ID is assigned incrementally, and Date is just a datetime stamp of whenever I added the information, I want to check against the Name and Phone as the criteria to tell if this is a unique entry.

This is the INSERT statement I have so far:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (ID, name, phone, date)";
```

It works. I also have a statement which uses SELECT to determine if the row is there, and then runs this script if it isn't. It's probably overly complicated.

I've researched, and have found minimal information on this. (So maybe there's a better approach?) I've found some resources, like [INSERT a new if it doesn't exist, and UPDATE if it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813578/insert-a-new-if-it-doesnt-exist-and-update-if-it-does), which doesn't quite answer my question because I need to compare it against my "name" and "phone" columns, not the unique ID.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Perhaps look into ```REPLACE```, which works exactly like ```INSERT```, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a ```PRIMARY KEY``` or a ```UNIQUE``` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)

Comment: @Brendan . . . There is not a way to do a hard `delete` and `insert` in the same statement (unless it is possible with some triggers).  That said, why not just use a *soft* delete.  That is, have a flag in the data the specifies if the row is valid.  You can do an `update` and `delete` in the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert only if not exists any data based on any column

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, name, phone, date) 
  SELECT '', 'anything', 'anything', 'anydate' 
  FROM dual 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT name, phone
          FROM table
          WHERE name = '35.86' AND phone = 'phonenumberhere'
        );
```

It's similar thing like running another select statement but it has little performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to *replace* the row, not `delete` it.  Here is one method:

```
insert into t (id, name, phone, date)
    values (id, name, phone, date)
    on duplicate key set id = values(id), date = values(date);
```

This assumes that `(name, phone)` has a unique index or is declared as a primary key:

```
create unique index unq_t_name_phone on t(name, phone);
```